# Probability: Third Draw from an urn having black and white balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> An urn contains 2 white and 2 black balls. A ball is drawn at random. If
>   it is white, it is not replaced into the urn. Otherwise it is replaced
>   with another ball of same colour. The process is repeated. Find the
>   probability that the third ball drawn is black.

[image]

I am getting the final answer as $5/8$ from my tree diagram. But in my book the answer is $23/30$. I don't know where I am going wrong. Please help.

Comment: There must be an arithmetical error, $85/72$ is not possible, it is larger than $1$.

Comment: How can you get a final answer that is larger than $1$? Your fractions simplify and add up to
$$
\frac16 + \frac29 + \frac19 + \frac 18 = \frac58
$$

Comment: Can you check the wording? A common problem is "it is replaced, together with another ball of the same colour."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question means to say that

> If you draw a white ball, then don't put back. If you draw black ball, then put ***two*** black balls back.

Or put another way,

> If it is white, it is not replaced (put back) into the urn. Otherwise it is replaced <strike>with</strike> ***alongside***   another ball of same color. The process is repeated. Find the probability that the third ball drawn is black.

---

Let $B_i,W_i$ be the events that you drew a white or black ball in the $i$th draw. Then,
\begin{align*}
P(B_3) &=P(B_2B_3)+P(W_2B_3)\\
&=P(B_1B_2B_3)+P(W_1B_2B_3)+P(B_1W_2B_3)+P(W_1W_2B_3)\\
&=P(B_3|B_2B_1)P(B_2|B_1)P(B_1)+P(B_3|B_2W_1)P(B_2|W_1)P(W_1)\\
&\qquad+P(B_3|W_2B_1)P(W_2|B_1)P(B_1)+P(B_3|W_2W_1)P(W_2|W_1)P(W_1)\\
&=\frac46\frac35\frac24+\frac34\frac23\frac24+\frac34\frac25\frac24+\frac22\frac13\frac24\\
&=\frac{23}{30}.
\end{align*}

Comment: But the question states "If it is white, it is not replaced into the urn. Otherwise it is replaced with another ball of same colour."

Comment: Yeah, that's another way to put what I said. Or, I just rephrased the question. In any case, Whatever the problem _meant_ is what I did so that the answer matches. I'm not saying that the wording is clear. I am saying that what I did is what the problem meant to say.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but for $BBB$, there are $2$ balls out of $4$ at start, and their number doesn't change according to the given condition, so how do you get $4/6 \times 3/5 \times 2/4$ and not just $(2/4)^3$ ?

Comment: Oh, hahahaha, I meant if draw white, then don't put back. If you draw black, then put ***two*** black back. Sorry, I thought that's what I wrote.

Comment: So if we want the given answer, we need to change the question ! So be it :)

Comment: Haha, I don't think it is changing the question. The author simply poorly conveyed the problem. I think I rephrased it above to convey his/her intentions more clearly.

Comment: Anyway, desired answer obtained (+1)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think this diagram shall help to understand the problem better. The final answer will be 23/30 and not 23/50.

Comment: I request somebody to attempt to MathJax in the above picture. It's a very helpful answer, as I see it.